# having trouble scraping results (links,dates) from a SEC page while using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i would like to copy links and dates associated with earnings/other reports(8k,10q) respectively for a specific stock. i have tried looping through the results table class but i am getting timeout error while using selenium. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you!

webpage:
[image]

approach 1)
[image]

approach 2) tired to loop through all the individual results xpath of the table:
[image]

#approach1

```
driver = setupDriver(download_path)
driver.get('https://sec.report/Document/Search/?queryCo=lvs&page=5')
formEle = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="formType"]')
    #formclick = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="formType"]/option[97]')
driverwait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driverwait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formType"]/option[97]'))).click()
     
#    //*[@id="filer1"]
driverwait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)

companyname = driverwait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "filer1")))
companyname.clear()
companyname.send_keys("TSLA")
searchEle = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="searchtext"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results"]/div[2]/table/tbody/a')))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

#approach 2 code

```
driver = setupDriver(download_path)
driver.get('https://sec.report/Document/Search/?queryCo=lvs&page=5')
formEle = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="formType"]')
    #formclick = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="formType"]/option[97]')
driverwait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
driverwait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formType"]/option[97]'))).click()
     
#    //*[@id="filer1"]
driverwait = WebDriverWait(driver,15)

companyname = driverwait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "filer1")))
companyname.clear()
companyname.send_keys("TSLA")
searchEle = getElements.clickHiddenEle(geshort,'//*[@id="searchtext"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/button')
href = []
for i in range(0,200):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="results"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td['+str(i)+']/div[1]')))
    headings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/div[1]')
    link = heading.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    x = link.get_attribute("href")
    href.append(x)
print(href)
```

Comment: Did you try their API?

Comment: Please share your code as text, not as picture

Comment: added the code snippets for both approaches, thanks!

Comment: i have not used their API, will look into it, if i can not solve this problem. thanks!

Comment: Tip: Selinium should be a last resort for scraping data. 1st port of call should be to expose the api, failing that there many other tools I would use over Selinium (Scrapy, Playright, BeutifulSoup.......)

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: if page has API then you should first try to use it. Server will not block access to `API`  (because it is for running scripts) but it may block access when it detects Selenium or other tool for scraping web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that OP's next question will contain code, not images, and a minimal reproducible example, here is one solution to his conundrum.
As stated in comments, Selenium should be the last resort when web scraping - it is a tool meant for testing, not web scraping.
The following solution will extract dates, form names, form descriptions and form urls from the 11 pages worth of data concerning LVS:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Sample Company Name AdminContact@<sample company domain>.com'}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(1, 12)):
    r = s.get(f'https://sec.report/Document/Search/?queryCo=lvs&page={x}')
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    data_rows = soup.select('table.table tr')
    for row in data_rows:
        form_title = row.select('a')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        form_url = row.select('a')[0].get('href')
        form_desc = row.select('small')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        form_date = row.select('td')[-1].get_text(strip=True)
        big_list.append((form_date, form_title, form_desc, form_url))
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['Date', 'Title', 'Description', 'Url'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
Date    Title   Description Url
0   2022-09-14  8-K 8-K 8-K Form 8-K - Period Ending 2022-09-14 https://sec.report/Document/0001300514-22-000101/#lvs-20220914.htm
1   2022-08-29  40-APP/A 40-APP/A 40-APP/A  Form 40-APP https://sec.report/Document/0001193125-22-231550/#d351601d40appa.htm
2   2022-07-22  10-Q 10-Q 10-Q  Form 10-Q - Period Ending 2022-06-30    https://sec.report/Document/0001300514-22-000094/#lvs-20220630.htm
3   2022-07-20  8-K 8-K 8-K Form 8-K - Period Ending 2022-07-20 https://sec.report/Document/0001300514-22-000088/#lvs-20220720.htm
4   2022-07-11  8-K 8-K 8-K Form 8-K - Period Ending 2022-07-11 https://sec.report/Document/0001300514-22-000084/#lvs-20220711.htm
... ... ... ... ...
1076    2004-11-22  S-1/A S-1/A S-1/A   Form S-1    https://sec.report/Document/0001047469-04-034893/#a2143958zs-1a.htm
1077    2004-10-25  S-1/A S-1/A S-1/A   Form S-1    https://sec.report/Document/0001047469-04-031910/#a2143958zs-1a.htm
1078    2004-10-20  8-K 8-K 8-K Form 8-K - Period Ending 2004-09-30 https://sec.report/Document/0001047469-04-031637/#a2145253z8-k.htm
1079    2004-10-08  UPLOAD LETTER   Form UPLOAD https://sec.report/Document/0000000000-04-032407/#filename1.txt
1080    2004-09-03  S-1 S-1 S-1 Form S-1    https://sec.report/Document/0001047469-04-028031/#a2142433zs-1.htm
1081 rows × 4 columns
```

You can extract other stuffs, like company name & person name (I imagine that would be the person filing the form).

Docs for BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
Also, requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
For TQDM, visit https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/
And for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

Comment: thank you very much your time on this. my bad for posting images, i am relatively new to this platform and will follow guidelines outlined going forward. Thanks again!